# ExecuteExcel4Macro Method fails in simple Excel 2011 macro on Mac with 1004 Error

Tags: excel

I receive the error message (Runtime 1004), in Excel 2011 for Mac, with a very simple Macro:

```
Sub Macro9()

    ExecuteExcel4Macro "(""Tabella pivot1"",""AREA"",TRUE)"

End Sub
```

which is the trivial record of the "Expand" command on a pivot table.

I'd appreciate any suggestion, thank you in advance.

Comment: Read [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193589.aspx). Specifically this: *"The Microsoft Excel 4.0 macro isn't evaluated in the context of the current workbook or sheet. This means that any references should be external and should specify an explicit workbook name. For example, to run the Microsoft Excel 4.0 macro "My_Macro" in Book1 you must use "Book1!My_Macro()". If you don't specify the workbook name, this method fails."*

Comment: Yes, I've seen it, but unfortunately it doesn't make much sense to me. I'd need a more practical indication...